# Blutooth PXC 550-II as Headset on Windows 10 : Cannot activate "Handsfree telephony" because "The parameter is incorrect"

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth, wireless-headset

My PXC 550-II used to work just fine as a headset - until this morning where Windows just wouldn't capture any sound from its microphone (as per the little indicator next to the corresponding entry in Sound Settings > Recording). It works just fine with my phone though, both as headphones and as headset.

I now have unpaired it from my PC, restarted my headset, and paired with it again, and now there is no related entry any more in "Recording", nor is there an entry for the headset mode in "Playback" (there is however an entry for my device as "Headphones" i.e. for audio playback only, and it works as expected).

[Screenshot of device entry as headphones in Sound > Playback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIRKA.png)

I went to Device Manager > Right click on my device > Properties > Services and saw that "Handsfree telephony" was deactivated. I tried to activate it but got ["The parameter is incorrect."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyp1W.png). Help ?

Answer (score 0):

After multiple attempts at unpairing and pairing again, and also leaving the headset off and plugged into power for a (long) while, and unpairing and pairing again, the headset function just appeared back, and now the "Handsfree telephony" service is checked.

I would still be interested in an explanation though, but I just wanted to post this for anyone facing these problems - there is hope !